# IIS Rewrite Module Subdomain

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, dns, subdomain, episerver

Im working on a new website for a customer.
The site is hosted in Episerverhosting.com.

They have today public sub-domains such as (example)

- digital.nor.se
- customer.nor.se

hosted on wordpress or something.

and the main site:

- www.nor.se

I need to redirect http://digital.nor.se to www.nor.se/parent/child/granchild

So when we go public and www.nor.se get pointed to our new episerver site i need to check for sub-domain and redirect to pages at the main website.

When i RDP to our server this is how the IIS is configured:

- only one site in iis named nor.se
- only one site binding for IP-address *

So as in my understanding the * binding will answer for all request.

Is it possible to use Url Rewrite to set up rules that check for sub-domains and redirect. I tried this:

**Using:** Regular Expressions

**Pattern:** (.*)

**Conditions:**(digitalinsights).nor.episerverhosting.com$

**Action type:** Redirect

Does not work.
Have you an example for a better pattern that check for a specific sub-domain?maybe something like:
(digitalinsights).(whatever?) -

I tried this on my local machine.
Where instead of * as site binding i added for example
digital.nor.local¨
customer.nor.local
and added it in the hosts file.

this did work.

But i would like to **not** add new site bindings on the episerver hosting server.

I would be glad for help.

BR

Answer (score -1):

IIS rewrite rules will work for your scenario.

The domain(s) need to point to the web server, and they need to be bound to the IIS instance (either wildcard or explicitly).

There are numerous [rewrite examples here](https://host4asp.net/top-iis-rewrite-rules/).

**PS.** There's nothing Episerver-specific about this - IIS will redirect the requests before they reach the web app.

Comment: Is it better to create a new website in IIS called for example NorRedirects and point it to a folder only containing a web.config with rules for redirect to main site? If i do this i dont need to modify the main website web.config.  So this new website pointing to a folder only containing web.config with rules are binding to digital.nor.se and customer.nor.se. And this is also added in the hosts file on the server like: "127.0.0.1 digital.nor.se". The main website have an empty HostName and * for IP.

Comment: I wrote a clarification on swedish in this thread. That might help if you would like to straighten things out for me.

Comment: the link is broken on numerous rewrite example. please provide actual example in your answer.